# failed to install syft

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-wheel, python-netifaces

```
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for netifaces
  Running setup.py clean for netifaces
Failed to build netifaces
Installing collected packages: netifaces, dnspython, win32-setctime, Werkzeug, torch, pylibsrtp, pyee, itsdangerous, google-crc32c, cryptography, click, av, aioice, websocket-client, torchvision, torchcsprng, syft-proto, sqlitedict, requests-toolbelt, PyYAML, PyNaCl, PyJWT, pyarrow, names, loguru, forbiddenfruit, flask, dpcontracts, aiortc, syft
    Running setup.py install for netifaces ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

### ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\saam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\saam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n38dpvc6\netifaces_f5d8f5f2fe0e47cf89c8a833bc6962da\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\saam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n38dpvc6\netifaces_f5d8f5f2fe0e47cf89c8a833bc6962da\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\saam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-nd02t3mw'
cwd: C:\Users\saam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n38dpvc6\netifaces_f5d8f5f2fe0e47cf89c8a833bc6962da
Complete output (11 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building 'netifaces' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -DNETIFACES_VERSION=0.11.0 -IC:\Users\saam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\saam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt /Tcnetifaces.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\netifaces.obj
netifaces.c
C:\Users\saam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\pyconfig.h(200): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

ERROR: Failed building wheel for netifaces

Comment: What's your OS? Also, is it really the entire error message?

Comment: Windows 11
no, it is not I can not. I couldn't post all the error messages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The output gives the idea. I tried to run `pip install pytorch` which indeed gave me an error. Then there was written in output    `Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"`. This clearly says that you have to use `pip install torch which will install the pytorch`

Comment: i have this problem in this command too
pip install syft